# Cant run django server because of cx_oracle

Tags: django, cx-oracle

i pull my friend code in github , and when i want to run it with django

```
*path*>workon test
(test)*path*>py manage.py runserver
```

Here is the error I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\u532246\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\oracle\base.py", line 47, in <module>
    import cx_Oracle as Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cx_Oracle'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\u532246\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\users\u532246\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\u532246\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\u532246\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\u532246\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\u532246\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\u532246\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\u532246\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\u532246\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\u532246\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\u532246\Envs\test\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\u532246\Desktop\skripsi\Django-master\polls\models.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Question(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\u532246\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 117, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\u532246\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\u532246\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 204, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\u532246\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\u532246\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 201, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\u532246\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\u532246\Envs\test\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\u532246\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\oracle\base.py", line 49, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading cx_Oracle module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading cx_Oracle module: No module named 'cx_Oracle'
```

I already put the oracle modulein advance system setting , but its still not working , i wonder if i put the wrong file or not there is something i havent set to make it work

Comment: what os are you on?

Comment: Here is the cx_Oracle installation manual: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html

Comment: @gregory win10 64 bit

Comment: @ChristopherJones thankyou i already find the error  , the problem is my python and cx_oracle didnt have the same bit , so when i install python 64 bit , the problem is solved right away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already find the solution :

> 1. Check if your python has the same bit with cx_oracle , perhaps cx_oracle will be installed the same bit like your OS has .
> 2. if it didnt have the same bit , you must download the python the same bit like your OS does , if it is 64 bit then your python must 64 bit